# Marklogic - Apply TDE for a single document

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

We have different taxonomy documents stored in content database under a folder named "/docs/".And, I have a requirement to apply Marklogic TDE for each of the taxonomy file present in the folder to view different taxonomy data as tables.

I tried giving  value in template as "/docs/" for all the templates and the context value with the unique node value for each taxonomy.But since we have given /docs/ in directory ,it is getting applied to all the taxonomy files but I need each template specific to a single taxonomy.

I also tried giving file path in  in template but it didn't work.Could anyone please help me with the below questions.

- Is it possible to apply a TDE template on a single document?
- If so, please provide a way to apply it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume there is no unique id field on the document itself? I have in the past created a TDE with context like /document[@id="1234"]

Comment: @BenW Thanks for your comment! I have tried the similar way based on document title.During extraction of data, this is working fine.But, during ingestion of data, since I have other files under the same directory,it is getting applied to all the documents and hence some the files are failing validation and not getting inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the document in a unique [collection](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/collections) and then use the [collection scope](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_30414) to restrict the TDE.

> A `<collections>` section defines the scope of the template to be confined only to documents in specific collections

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We have around 50 taxonomy documents and those are loaded via ML REST API(PUT v1/documents) from an external system.So,it is difficult to maintain many collections for each of the documents.

Comment: You could also look to assert the URI in a predicate on the context expression, to limit to just the docs that have a `base-uri()` for the one doc you want to match i.e.: `<context>/doc[base-uri()='/taxonomy/123.xml']</context>` However, that may not be the most performant (reindexing may match all docs and filter to find the one that matches).

Comment: This is working! Thank you so much!